# Android Calendar application not returning to my activity

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I am working on inserting data to user's default calendar app according to the [documentation.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html) The documentation clearly says the following:

> When you use the intents, your application sends users to the Calendar application to perform the desired operation in a pre-filled form. After they're done, they're returned to your application. By designing your application to perform common operations through the Calendar, you provide users with a consistent, robust user interface.

But I am unable to return to my application using intents as given below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime)
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, myTitle)
    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, myDescription)
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, eventLoc)
    .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
//startActivityForResut(intent);//also doesnot work 
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there a way to get back to my activity from calendar app. I am testing on Google Nexus tablet.